# Не вставлять значение если оно уже есть в базе

Tags: php, sql

**Где я здесь ошибся, может ошибки в синтаксисе ?**

```
  $query =    "INSERT INTO userssum (tell,tellto,uniqum,status) values ('$tell','$tellto','$uniqum',$status) AS tmp WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT uniqum FROM userssum WHERE uniqum = '$uniqum') LIMIT 1";
```

Comment: Вы можете для поля "uniqum" задать индекс на уникальность

Comment: Да, ошибка в синтаксисе - INSERT .. VALUES не допускает WHERE. Но задача решается проще - уникальным индексом на требуемую комбинацию полей и использованием INSERT IGNORE для подавления ошибки. PS. Это если не считать ошибкой прямую подстановку параметров в текст запроса.

Comment: Спасибо всем!!!

Answer (score 0):

В описанной ситуации лучше воспользоваться уникальным ключом

```
ALTER TABLE userssum ADD CONSTRAINT unq_userssum UNIQUE (uniqum);
```

Но также можно использовать конструкцию `INSERT INTO SELECT`

```
INSERT INTO userssum (tell,tellto,uniqum,status) 
SELECT
  '$tell','$tellto','$uniqum',$status
FROM dual 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT uniqum FROM userssum WHERE uniqum = '$uniqum')
```